# strtok overwrites my variables

Tags: c, strtok

I'm trying to use strtok () to store info into my struct.  My code looks like this

```
char *tempType = NULL, name[100], fileString[100];
int *tempItems = NULL, *tempCost = NULL;
FILE *infile = NULL;
ItemType myVector;

infile = fopen ("grocery_list.txt", "r");

while (!feof (infile))
{
    fscanf (infile, "%s", &fileString);
    tempType = strtok (fileString, ":");
    tempCost = (int *) strtok (NULL, ":");
    tempItems = (int *) strtok (NULL,":");
    myVector.type[num_items] = tempType;
    myVector.cost[num_items] = tempCost;
    myVector.items[num_items] = tempItems;
    num_items++;
}
```

Everytime I run it, all the values in myVector.type becomes "cherries" and I'm not sure why.  My infile:
apples:5:1 
milk:3:2
bread:3:1
candy:10:1
cheese:5:6
oranges:4:2
cherries:3:2

Comment: This doesn't compile. There's no variable called `num_items`.

Comment: sorry the line above has int num_items = 0; but I forgot to copy it over

Comment: Correct this: `fscanf (infile, "%s", &fileString);` as `fscanf (infile, "%s", fileString);`

Answer (score 1):

The function strtok returns a pointer and this pointer gets overwritten with each execution of the while loop. So in the end all array entries point to the same memory address. You need to copy the string strtok returns.

Comment: so I tried adding: 
strcpy (name, temp);
myVector.type[num_items] = name;
but the same problem keeps occuring

Comment: How is ItemType defined?

Comment: typedef struct ItemType
{
 char *type[100];
 int *cost[100];
 int *items[100];
} ItemType;

Comment: The definition is incorrect: it needs to be char type[100], or you need to malloc the memory